# how to identify Gmail Account Type using Google API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I want to identify if the connected Gmail Account is a GSUITE (Paid Account) or a normal Trial account.
Which Gmail/Google API call should i use to identify this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no method in [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) that does such thing. You're best bet is to email the account and ask him/her.

Comment: the application has thousands of users connecting their google account. Then the application (in the background) sends emails on their behalf. I would want to know the EMAIL SEND LIMITS of connected google account ,that is why i would like to know if the account belongs to GSUITE group or normal group

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get). All paid accounts require that users register a domain and you can use the Google+ API to detect if a domain is associated with an account (free personal accounts cannot have domains associated with them).

Another way to do it is to check a user's drive storage quota via the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v3/drive.about.get). The free personal account allows a max of 15GB, whereas Google's paid accounts offer 30GB (for GSuite Basic) or unlimited.

Comment: Is this Process of Identification of Account Types vetted by Google. Is this reliable?

Comment: I can't say whether or not Google supports these as canonical methods to identify account type. But they should be reliable as long as Google holds to requiring paid accounts to have domains and keeps to the current storage quotas for free and paid accounts.